# limit: 1 difference in schema.rb boolean fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, git, rails-migrations

I recently started noticing that following a deployment to production, I see this git diff in my `db/schema.rb` there:

```
-    t.boolean  "published",          limit: 1
+    t.boolean  "published"
```

and

```
-    t.boolean  "visible",            limit: 1,                    default: false
+    t.boolean  "visible",                                         default: false
```

Given that the Rails version is the same on both environments, is this just caused by the difference between MySQL versions, respectively 5.5.43 on production and 5.6.23 on development?

Comment: MySQL version is probably irrelevant here. You just have the `limits` in your production database, which were added there earlier somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Has your Rails version changed? There was a recent change in Rails that could account for this: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19066

Basically, since MySQL doesn't have a boolean column type, Rails uses  a `TINYINT(1)` column type for `:boolean` attributes, which was reflected when the schema was dumped to `schema.rb`. So far, so good. But then if one tried to load the same `schema.rb` into PostgreSQL it would fail because Postgres *does* have a `BOOLEAN` column type, but declaring a length for `BOOLEAN` columns is illegal. This bug was fixed by removing the `limit: 1` option when dumping `:boolean` attributes from a MySQL database (it wasn't necessary anyway).

So if the last time your schema was dumped (which happens when you run migrations) you were on Rails 4.2.2 or earlier you would have gotten `limit: 1` in `schema.rb`, and if you subsequently upgraded to 4.2.3 and dumped your schema again the `limit: 1` would be gone.

This change doesn't have any effect except for fixing the aforementioned bug—your `schema.rb` will function exactly the same way it did before—so there's nothing to be concerned about.